# Display time inside a clock time after performing mathematical operations

Tags: r, datetime, time, time-series

I have created a time sequence from **00:00:00 hrs** to **23:00:00 hrs**. Adding any number of hours is easy until the sum is less than or equal to 23:00:00 hrs. After the sum crosses 23:00:00 it start displaying the time in number of days which is quite intuitive.But I want the output inside a clock time irrespective of whether I do subtraction or addition

Suppose I want to do addition like below

```
library(chron)
times("23:00:00")+ times("01:00:00")
Time in days:
[1] 1
```

**My desired output is** below one. Instead of getting days I want

```
00:00:00
```

I also tried subtraction

```
times("00:00:00")- times("01:00:00")
[1] -0.04166667
```

**Desired output**

```
 "23:00:00"
```

I also tried it with **POSIXct** but it gives various error at various instances

```
 as.POSIXct("00:00:00", format = "%H:%M:%S", tz = "UTC")
    [1] "2017-02-07 UTC" #Not printing time. Only dates
```

Subtraction using POSIXct

```
as.POSIXct("00:00:00", format = "%H:%M:%S", tz = "UTC") -as.POSIXct("01:00:00", format = "%H:%M:%S", tz = "UTC")
        Time difference of -1 hours
        Warning message:
        In 1:0:0 : numerical expression has 2 elements: only the first used
```

Addition using POSIXct

```
as.POSIXct("23:00:00", format = "%H:%M:%S", tz = "UTC") + as.POSIXct("01:00:00", format = "%H:%M:%S", tz = "UTC")
Error in `+.POSIXt`(as.POSIXct("23:00:00", format = "%H:%M:%S", tz = "UTC"),  : 
  binary '+' is not defined for "POSIXt" objects
```

Please help me to crack this problem. Also please help me to print the time along with date in POSIXct shown above Please let me know if anything doesn't make sense to you instead of down vote my question.

Comment: Have you tried defining `as.POSIXct( format = "%Y-%m-%d %H:%M:%S")`. Leave the year, month and day as 0, but initialize it. It would help you keep a track. Also in R there is a `difftime` function that subtracts time between two datetimes. I would use that rather than subtracting it.

Comment: Where is `times` defined?

Comment: @nrussell it is in the chron library

Comment: @Dinesh.hmn My aim wasn't measure the time difference .

Comment: Its a function that you can use instead of manually subtracting time, as it takes care of the background formats and returns results in the format you specified, so just an easy method as an alternative.

Comment: just an helpful item while you're thinking on such issues: you're getting the actual number here because that's what POSIXct is; a count of seconds from a certain time. it's not actually time itself, it's a relative position by number. this is why you have to make the conversions recommended below.

Answer (score 3):

Note that `times` of `chron` package internally represents time as a numeric value (decimal days). What you are trying to do is retain the values after the decimal and remove the integer before it. This can be achieved by taking modulus by 1 (try `2.5 %% 1`). So, you can just take modulus by `times(1)` and that will get rid of the day.

```
library(chron)
(times("23:00:00")+ times("01:00:00")) %% times(1)
#[1] 00:00:00
> (times("00:00:00") - times("01:00:00")) %% times(1)
#[1] 23:00:00
```

**Using POSIXct**

I would not prefer to use `POSIXct` for this since `POSIXct` complicates things due to dates and timezones. Internally, `POSIXct` are numeric values of seconds from some origin (usually 1970-01-01). So, if you want to add a time interval to a `POSIXct` object, just add that time interval in seconds.

To add 1 hour to "23:00:00", you can do

```
format(as.POSIXct(
       as.numeric(as.POSIXct("23:00:00", format = "%H:%M:%S", tz = "UTC")) + 3600,
       origin = "1970-01-01", tz = "UTC"), "%H:%M:%S")
#[1] "00:00:00"
```

Subtraction can work in the same way

```
format(as.POSIXct(
       as.numeric(as.POSIXct("24:00:00", format = "%H:%M:%S", tz = "UTC")) - 3600,
       origin = "1970-01-01", tz = "UTC"), "%H:%M:%S")
#[1] "23:00:00"
```

Answer (score 1):

For both addition and subtraction, what you need is to keep only the fractional part of the results, throwing away the integer part. It is easy to write simple functions to do this.

```
library(chron)

hoursum  = function(t1, t2) { t1 + t2 - floor(t1+t2) }
hourdiff = function(t1, t2) { t1 - t2 - floor(t1-t2) }
```

Now you can do all of the computations you want

```
hoursum(times("23:00:00"), times("01:00:00"))
## [1] 00:00:00
hoursum(times("23:00:00"), times("02:00:00"))
## [1] 01:00:00
hourdiff(times("00:00:00"), times("01:00:00"))
## [1] 23:00:00
hourdiff(times("02:00:00"), times("03:00:00"))
## [1] 23:00:00
hourdiff(times("02:00:00"), times("03:15:00"))
## [1] 22:45:00
```

Answer (score 1):

If you actually want to change the way that the times are stored in the variable, so that they are within 0 to 24 hrs, then a simple one line function will suffice:

```
clock = function(x)  x - floor(x)
clock(times("23:00:00") + times("02:00:00"))
# [1] 01:00:00
```

If you just want the printed display to be always in 24hr format, then the simplest is to edit the S3 print method for objects of class `times`.

Typing `chron:::print.times` will show you how this function is written in the package.  You can make one simple tweak to get what you want (note I also include the full code for the edited function at the end of this post, so you can just copy/paste rather than changing it yourself): at start of `print.times`, add the line `x = x-floor(x)`.

**Testing it works:**

```
times("00:00:00") - times("01:00:00")
# [1] 23:00:00
times("23:00:00") + times("01:00:00")
#   [1] 00:00:00
times("23:00:00") + times("02:00:00")
#   [1] 01:00:00
times("3:00:00") - times("22:00:00")
# [1] 05:00:00
```

NB, one advantage of doing it this way is that it will also work with  operations other than `+` and `-`.  For example:

```
sum(c(times("23:00:00"), times("22:00:00"), times("21:00:00"), times("20:00:00")))
# [1] 14:00:00
mean(c(times("23:00:00"), times("22:00:00"), times("21:00:00"), times("20:00:00")))
# [1] 21:30:00
cumsum(c(times("23:00:00"), times("22:00:00"), times("21:00:00"), times("20:00:00")))
# [1] 23:00:00 21:00:00 18:00:00 14:00:00
```

#### The complete function to copy and paste into your console:

Note that I also added a parameter `normalise` to the function, so that the original functionality of the method is remains available if you specify `normalise = FALSE` when printing.

```
print.times = function (x, digits, quote = FALSE, prefix = "", simplify, normalise = TRUE, ...) 
{
  if (normalise) x = x-floor(x)
  if (!as.logical(length(x))) {
    cat("times(0)\n")
    return(invisible(x))
  }
  if (missing(simplify) && is.null(simplify <- getOption("chron.simplify"))) 
    simplify <- FALSE
  xo <- x
  if (all(is.na(x)) || any(x[!is.na(x)] >= 1)) 
    cat("Time in days:\n")
  x <- format.times(x, simplify = simplify)
  NextMethod("print", quote = quote)
  invisible(xo)
}
environment(print.times) <- environment(chron:::print.times)
```

Answer (score 0):

You can use the [lubridate](https://github.com/hadley/lubridate) package easily enough.

- Add time strings each wrapped in `hms()`, which converts to time format.
- Overcome 24 hours clock challenge by adding any date without a time (e.g., `today()`).
- Resulting time (ignoring date) will be what you're after.

Examples:

```
library(lubridate)

x <- today() + hms("23:00:00") + hms("2:00:00")
format(x, "%H:%M:%S")
#> [1] "01:00:00"

x <- today() + hms("00:00:00") - hms("1:00:00")
format(x, "%H:%M:%S")
#> [1] "23:00:00"
```